# FATAL_ERROR System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller, code-coverage

I get this error from my testclass

> FATAL_ERROR System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

I have a LIMIT 1 and [0] om my queries why do I get out of bounds?

> Controller

```
public class NavigateToProfielController {
@AuraEnabled
public static String getLoggedInUser(){
    User ContactUser =[SELECT Id, ContactId FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
    Profiel__c currentUser = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id from Contacts__r WHERE Id=:Contactuser.ContactId) FROM Profiel__c LIMIT 1][0];
    if(currentUser.Id!= null){
        system.debug('currentUser.Id '+ currentUser.Id);
        return currentUser.Id;    
    }else{
        return 'NULL';
    }
}
```

}

> Testclass

```
@isTest
public class NavigateToProfielControllerTest{  
    private static testMethod void ProfielControllerTest(){
        NavigateToProfielController.getLoggedInUser();
    }
}
```

> My codecoverage Is only 50%, for the first 5 lines

Comment: The tests can't see the current data of your org. You have to insert test date before runing your test. In your case, you have to insert contacts and Profiel__c  objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in this line you are fetching 0 index record.

```
`Profiel__c currentUser = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id from Contacts_`_r WHERE Id=:Contactuser.ContactId) FROM Profiel__c LIMIT 1][0];
```

But in your test class you didn't create any test record for this. So you need to create test record here.

Or you can do

```
Profiel__c currentUser = new Profiel__c();
List<Profiel__c> currentUserList = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id from Contacts_`_r WHERE Id=:Contactuser.ContactId) FROM Profiel__c LIMIT 1];
if(currentUserList.size() > 0)
currentUser  = currentUserList[0];
```